# Splash screen in addActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, splash-screen, actionlistener

I need to show a splash screen on button click. When I click the button the splash has to be visible, I do some process which runs on the background. After the background process finishes, the splash has to disappear. I used the following code, but the splash doesn't visible. When I use the same code in main class, it works.

```
btnClickToMove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JWindow window = new JWindow();
                    window.getContentPane().add(
                                    new JLabel("Loading JFrame...", SwingConstants.CENTER));
                    window.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 100);
                    window.setVisible(true);
                    try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    // my process which runs on background.......

      window.setVisible(false);
      window.dispose();
        }
            });
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(5000);`  Don't do that.  Use a single shot (Swing) `Timer` if need be, but don't choke the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

Don't perform long running tasks on the EDT.  Use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), and see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.